How to suppress 'refers to relative ssh reference' warning?
I've got an application recipe that fetches the source code from a Git repository. The application's repository includes submodule(s). To fetch the source code with submodule(s), I use the below SRC_URI. Notice gitsm instead of git, see.
SRC_URI += "gitsm://<repo address>;protocol=ssh;branch=development"

When I compile this recipe, the below warning appears.
WARNING: <recipe name>-1.0+gitAUTOINC+60c254fbd3-r0 
do_fetch: Submodule included by gitsm://<repo address>;protocol=ssh;branch=development refers to relative ssh reference <submodule address>.  
References may fail if not absolute

How can I suppress this warning?

Additional info:

BitBake 2.4.0
Poky 4.2 Mickledore
Ubuntu 22.04


All you need to do is to make sure you are cloning the source code as you expected - that is what this warning is about. Also if the app compiles okay, you can skip the warning too.

I've no problem with the compilation. It's all about how annoying the output of the build is.

I understand what you mean, just think its just advanced version of C++ compilation warning :)

@rakib_ Life goes on then :)

Check your .gitmodules file in the <repo address> repository. It probably looks something like this:
[submodule "<submodule>"]
    path = path/to/submodule
    url = <submodule address>

If the submodule is hosted in the same location as the main repository (e.g. github.com/username/repo and github.com/username/submodule), you can use a relative submodule URL, which will remove the warning. It would look like
[submodule "<submodule>"]
    path = path/to/submodule
    url = ../submodule

If your submodule is hosted elsewhere (e.g. github.com/username/repo and github.com/otheruser/submodule or gitlab.com/someotheruser/submodule), then you're stuck using an absolute URL, which results in these bitbake warnings.
Relevant documentation in the git reference:

<repository> is the URL of the new submodule’s origin repository. This may be either an absolute URL, or (if it begins with ./ or ../), the location relative to the superproject’s default remote repository (Please note that to specify a repository foo.git which is located right next to a superproject bar.git, you’ll have to use ../foo.git instead of ./foo.git - as one might expect when following the rules for relative URLs - because the evaluation of relative URLs in Git is identical to that of relative directories).


Relative submodule paths are great! It allows developers to pick their transport (ssh, https) when cloning the main repository and their selected transport will be inherited by the submodule as well.
